# Hiding the Android Keyboard's Input Box (Not the Keyboard Inself)

Tags: android

I want the keyboard letters/numbers only to show when I hit an edit box. So I do want the keyboard minus its large upper input box.  The actual text I would like to see go into the edit box and not into the large input box appearing above the keyboard.   This blocks the view of the whole screen and is not the look and feel that I want.  Should have noted that I'm in full screen mode.

Comment: What you describe is quite vague, please supply a screenshot if you can.

Comment: I'm just saying that when the keyboard comes up it has this LARGE input box that obscures the view of the form. I don't want the input box to take up this much space so I am looking to eliminate it or reduce it in size and have entered text appear on screen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but you might want to take a look at [Onscreen Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html), **resize mode**. The explanation and sample codes are quite detailed.

Comment: I looked at this what I am trying to do is to have the IME but remove its separate edit area.

Comment: as an update resize does not work for full-screen mode which is what I am using.